# How to keep my external HDDs alive the most possible time without damage?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, cron

I have read from many people in the past that it is better for a hard drive to be awake and running the whole time 24/7 than been constantly turning on and off every few minutes. If this is not accurate, please correct me.

In the meantime, here is my situation and my setup. I have a Dell Laptop Latitude E6420 with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2540M CPU @ 2.60GH, 4GB of RAM, and an internal 128GB SSD HD. It currently has ArchLinux (headless version) and it is using on average 10 Watts of power when idle.

I am using this computer as a server for hosting plex media server, nas, nginx (instead of Apache), mysql, and seafile (my hosting solution like owncloud). All my files that are hosted in the nas and seafile server are stored on two external 1TB 2.5 HDD 5400 RPM USB 3.0 drives set as RAID1 to avoid risking losing data.

The problem that I have is that these external drives are constantly been going to sleep (spinning down) and being reawaken, which as far as I know, it is very bad for the drives and can shorten their lives. I have tried changing/remove the standby settings with sdparm/hdparm but the drives do not support the setting. I have tried recompiling the Linux kernel but it did not work either.

So far, the best solution I have found (but I am not sure if it can affect negatively the disks), is to issue a `touch` command on both drives (i.e. `touch /dev/sdc1`) every two minutes with `cron`.

I saw another solution that was something like this (using `cron` as well):

```
dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/null count=1 skip=$RANDOM
```

But as far as I can tell it interacts even more with the drive (the LEDs on the drive blink much more indicating more disk activity) which do not believe its good on the long run for the drives.

Is there a better solution?